# How do I align word phrases horizontally in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I use Texmaker, and currently my section looks like this:

```
BCC Cr\\
1.00                \# Scaling factor for the lattice constant\\
2.8850 0.0 0.0      \# Real lattice vectors\\
0.0 2.8850 0.0\\
0.0 0.0 2.8850\\
2                   \# Number of atoms of Cr in the unit cell\\
Direct              \# Fractional coordinates\\
0.00 0.00 0.00      \# Positions of the atoms in the unit cell\\
0.50 0.50 0.50\\\\
```

I have intentionally indented the phrases beginning with /# to explain what I want to see in my report. I wish for those phrases to be vertically aligned. I know there is an \align function, but that would turn the whole thing into math input. Is there a text version of \align? Eventually, I wish my end result to look like this (in PDF):

```
BCC Cr
1.00                # Scaling factor for the lattice constant
2.8850 0.0 0.0      # Real lattice vectors
0.0 2.8850 0.0
0.0 0.0 2.8850
2                   # Number of atoms of Cr in the unit cell
Direct              # Fractional coordinates
0.00 0.00 0.00      # Positions of the atoms in the unit cell
0.50 0.50 0.50
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have found a solution to my own problem, which is to use a table.

The following works:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
BCC Cr\\
1.00               &\# Scaling factor for the lattice constant\\
2.8850 0.0 0.0     &\# Real lattice vectors\\
0.0 2.8850 0.0\\
0.0 0.0 2.8850\\
2                  &\# Number of atoms of Cr in the unit cell\\
Direct             &\# Fractional coordinates\\
0.00 0.00 0.00     &\# Positions of the atoms in the unit cell\\
0.50 0.50 0.50\\\\
\end{tabular}\\
```

{ll} defines my table to have 2 columns and are left-aligned. The &'s work the same way as in align.

Answer (score -1):

```
\begin{vplace}[0.7]
This is some text to be centred vertically.
\end{vplace}
```

I think this will work

Comment: Sorry, but that does not solve my problem. I am not trying to centre text vertically, but for some words on a line to be aligned with those on top of it.